# Hacer UPDATE con Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy practicando ejercicios en SQL y me encontre con el siguiente problema:

**6. Debido a una paritaria efectuada en la organización, se producirá un aumento salarial para aquellos empleados con sueldos inferiores a 6000 dentro de los Estados Unidos. El valor deberá llevarse a 7000.**

Por lo que estoy usando un UPDATE. Quiero saber lo que estoy haciendo mal, cuando ejecuto la secuencia me tira el siguiente error:

**ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended **

Estoy usando el Live SQL que proporciona ORACLE, y no me deja usar "as" para nombrar las tablas. Cualquier cosa que necesiten, pregunten.
Este es mi código:

```
SET employees.SALARY = 7000
FROM hr.employees
inner join hr.departments
on employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
inner join hr.locations
on departments.LOCATION_ID = locations.LOCATION_ID
WHERE (employees.SALARY < 6000) AND (COUNTRY_ID = 'US')
```

**EDIT:**

Eh intentado otras formas, la que más me estaba convenciendo era la que ven a continuación pero me salta el error  **ORA-00971: missing SET keyword** cuando lo estoy usando.

```
UPDATE (
SELECT
employees.DEPARTMENT_ID,
departments.DEPARTMENT_ID,
departments.LOCATION_ID,
locations.LOCATION_ID
FROM hr.employees
INNER JOIN hr.departments on departments.DEPARTMENT_ID = employees.DEPARTMENT_ID
INNER JOIN hr.locations on locations.LOCATION_ID =departments_ID)
),
SET employees.SALARY = 7000
WHERE employees.SALARY<6000 AND locations.LOCATION_ID ='US';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
set a.SALARY = 7000
from employees a, --aqui el alias de la tablas employees es a
departments b,
locations c
where a.DEPARTMENT_ID = b.DEPARTMENT_ID and
b.LOCATION_ID = c.LOCATION_ID  and
(a.SALARY < 6000) AND (COUNTRY_ID = 'US');
```

Antes de ejecutar la consulta debes identificar a que tabla pertenece

```
COUNTRY_ID
```

Si es de location entonces quedaria asi:

```
set a.SALARY = 7000
    from employees a,
    departments b,
    locations c
    where a.DEPARTMENT_ID = b.DEPARTMENT_ID and
    b.LOCATION_ID = c.LOCATION_ID  and
    (a.SALARY < 6000) AND (c.COUNTRY_ID = 'US');
```

Comment: Henriquez eh intentado también tu opción pero o no supe hacerlo o no funciona, muchas gracias!